# Can you use weaved type mesh wire or is welded type mesh wire needed for rodent protection?

Tags: protection, rodent

In another question it was suggested to use 3mm meshsize mesh wire against rodent protection. Is it ok to use weaved type mesh opposed to welded type mesh? Or can rodents push through weaved type mesh?

Answer (score 3):

If the joints or cross  points are not welded then rodents will push a hole through that flexible mesh.

Comment: I can see that this is possible.  When I google, most sites show welded mesh, some do not.

Comment: My solution, for a foundation gap, was to stuff it with a mix of steel wool and spray foam. I don't think any critter is going to want to chew through that.