# Can mice chew through fine grade steel wool?

Tags: pest-control

I found conflicting information regarding this topic.

This [steel wool manufacturer](https://ekksol.com/steel-wool-against-mice-rats-rodents) states that:

> Use stainless steel wool grade MEDIUM so that mice, rats and other rodents do not make them larger.

This [pest control company](https://kapturepest.com/how-to-use-steel-wool-to-keep-mice-out-of-your-house/) supports that argument:

> All you need is medium-grade steel wool, as it’s the best for sealing these holes.

In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFQHvy3qjYY) it is recommended to use fine grade steel wool as it is easy to handle and can be jammed into openings easily.

Is there a consensus as to which grade of steel wool to use?

Comment: Go for welded mesh, make sure it is a fine mesh: 1" square won't be much use. See https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/276307/97780

Comment: @SolarMike But welded mesh for small opening and cracks is more difficult to handle than steel wool. Isn't it?

Comment: What do you want? controlling rodent access or easy handling? Pick one...

Answer (score 1):

There is a type of copper mesh sold specifically for packing into  holes to deny passage to rodents. It is easier on human skin and does not rust.

Comment: What do you mean "easier on human skin"? Do you mean the metal shavings are designed not to cut like normal steel wool? Or is there inherently something more skin-friendly about copper vs. steel?

Comment: The copper mesh sold for this purpose does not cut the skin of a person cramming it into holes. And it does not shed fines as it is handled as does steel wool. I have never used copper wool but only looked at the web advertisements, but I have used steel wool and I hate the stuff.

Comment: Higher-quality, coil-cut steel wool sheds a lot less. Look for stuff intended for fine finishing rather than for scrubbing pots.

Comment: Steel rusts. Copper mesh for plugging rodent holes can be used in exterior or other damp locations. The copper mesh sold for this use is not expensive.